# How do i convert this multiple where cause SQL to eSQL?

Tags: entity-framework

T-SQL

```
USE [AdventureWorks];
SELECT p.* FROM Production.ProductCategory cat ,[Production].[ProductSubcategory] sub, [Production].[Product] p
WHERE cat.ProductCategoryID=1 AND sub.ProductCategoryID = cat.ProductCategoryID and p.ProductSubcategoryID = sub.ProductSubcategoryID
```

And i want to convert to eSQL for EntityDatasource

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProductDataSource" runat="server"  ConnectionString="name=AdventureWorksEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="AdventureWorksEntities"  EntitySetName="Product" 
    Where="EXISTS(SELECT VALUE cat FROM ProductCategory AS cat WHERE cat.ProductCategoryID=1) 
             AND EXISTS(SELECT VALUE sub FROM ProductSubcategory AS sub WHERE sub.ProductCategoryID = cat.ProductCategoryID) 
             AND it.ProductSubcategoryID = sub.ProductSubcategoryID) " 
    >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

But it is error.

**Update :**
Thanks devart hints,
I modify the query to

```
SELECT VALUE p FROM AdventureWorksEntities.ProductCategory AS cat, AdventureWorksEntities.ProductSubcategory AS sub, AdventureWorksEntities.Product AS p WHERE cat.ProductCategoryID=1 AND sub.ProductCategoryID = cat.ProductCategoryID and p.ProductSubcategoryID = sub.ProductSubcategoryID
```

It work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for the Selecting EntityDataSource event handler, for example:

```
string query = @"SELECT VALUE p FROM EntityContainer.ProductCategory as cat, EntityContainer.ProductSubcategory as sub, EntityContainer.Product as p WHERE cat.ProductCategoryID=1 AND sub.ProductCategoryID = cat.ProductCategoryID and p.ProductSubcategoryID = sub.ProductSubcategoryID";
EntityDataSource source = null; 
source = Page.FindControl("ProductDataSource") as EntityDataSource;
if(source != null) {
  source.EntitySetName = null;
  source.CommandText = query;
}
```

This code provides a strongly-typed result and uses the Where clause.

Comment: I have Test you query, it not works. The error message said something wrong near 'cat'. Even just CommandText="SELECT VALUE p FROM EntityContainer.Product p" ,still error.

Comment: @SilverNight, sorry, just a misprint. Updated the answer.